# x86-64 objdump vs pmap addresses

Tags: linker, gdb, elf, objdump, pmap

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("text at %p\n", main);
    int c = getchar();
}
```

Compiling the above code on VirtualBox Ubuntu 64 bit and running it, I get:

text at **0x55555555468a**

pmap:

**0000555555554000**      4K r-x-- a.out

However,

objdump -dj .text a.out | sed -n '/:/,/^$/p':

**000000000000068a** :

 68a:   55                      push   %rbp

gdb a.out

Dump of assembler code for function main:

   **0x000000000000068a** <+0>: push   %rbp

Entirely different addresses for **linked** code ?

Comment: What is the output of `file a.out` ? There are different relocation rules for different types of executable files.

Comment: > Entirely different addresses for linked code ? You are looking at [position-independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables), which is relocated to a random address at runtime.